# Content from .load() is not active on main page

Tags: php, jquery

I have these pages:

**information.php**

```
<div id='content'>Foo Bar</div>
```

**main.php**

```
<div id='main'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("information.php");
    $("#content").click(function() {
        alert("Worked!");
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the `<div>` with `id=content`, loaded from `information.php`, nothing happens. The console of Chrome doesn't report any errors either. If I manually put the content-div from `information.php` into my `main.php` page it all works fine. Why doesn't it work when I use jQuery load?

The jQuery main script is loaded in the  and all other jQuery functions I have made on the site works perfectly. It's when I load another page into my main page that the IDs from the loaded page doesn't work, or are not active of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The load-method hasn't finished, when the click-handler should set to the `div` with the id 'content'. Add a complete-handler as 2nd parameter to the [load-method](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("information.php", function() {
        $("#content").click(function() {
            alert("Worked!");
        });
    });
});
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQVYb/).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! I also have the same problem when I try to '.append' information to the '#main' div as well. I tried to see if I could do it the same way with '.append', but it doesn't seem to have a callback the same way. If I append '$("#main").append("<div id='content2'>Foo Bar 2</div>");' and then make a corresponding click-event in the main page, it doesn't work. I guess it's the same problem, but I can not pass function to append, right?

Comment: There is a big difference between `.load()` and `.append()`. `load` makes a request to the server, when the server answers the result will be placed into the matched element. `append` added the html code directly to the matched element. So you don't need to wait and no complete-handler is needed. So it should work. Maybe you had forgotten to use the new id 'content2' to set the click-event?

Comment: You have to set the new click-event direct after appending in the click-handler. E.g. see [your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/TQVYb/2/).